# How to re-map CapsLock on KBP Poker 3 when used as FN key?

Tags: keyboard

I'm currently using a KBP Poker 3 with the `CapsLock` key as a `FN` key (using dipswitch 3).  I'd like to still have `CapsLock`, but on the function layer (like `FN+Q`).  How can I remap `FN+Q` to `CapsLock` when I'm using the `CapsLock` key as an `FN` key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can re-map the `CapsLock` key, while still using it as a `FN` key.

1. Unplug the keyboard and turn dipswitch 3 off, so the `CapsLock` key works as a `CapsLock` key.
2. Plug the keyboard back in and program like normal, selecting a target key combo and then clicking the `CapsLock` key to re-map it.
3. Unplug the keyboard and turn dipswitch 3 back on.
4. Plug the keyboard back in.  The `CapsLock` key is back to being a `FN` key and your key combo should still be re-mapped to `CapsLock`.